# Mergo not overriding destination with source

Tags: go, merge

I am trying to merge values of 2 JSON into 1, where value of source should override value of destination. It is working fine for most the cases except for the case where value of 1 hashmap is string and other value is another hashmap. Below is the code snipped

`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/imdario/mergo"
)

var (
    a = "{\"a\": \"60\"}"
    b = "{\"a\": { \"name\":\"asprin\", \"dose\":0.12,\"stt\":true} }"
)

func main() {
    var source, destination map[string]interface{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(a), &destination)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(b), &source)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(destination, source)
    err = mergo.MergeWithOverwrite(&destination, &source, mergo.WithOverride, mergo.WithTypeCheck)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(&destination, "  <-- result")

}
```

`

playground:  [https://go.dev/play/p/BTmRc7wf6Js](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

Current output is

```
&map[a:60]   <-- result   which is value of destination. Mergo is not changing anything
```

Excepted output is

```
map[a:map[dose:0.12 name:asprin stt:true]]   <--result
```

or atleast give error that it is not possible to merge hashmap to string